# rasterio driver - weird bug that throws no error

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, rasterio

I am using rasterio to convert some png files to geotiff files.
My input is a geotiff and I do some processing to output a geotiff file using the following command:

```
        temp = cv2.imread(file)
        temp = cv2.cvtColor(temp, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        src = rasterio.open(geo_file)
        tmp_outpath = os.path.join(file.replace('.png', '.tif'))
        with rasterio.open(tmp_outpath, 'w', driver='GTiff', height=src.height, width=src.width,
                           count=temp.shape[2], crs=src.crs, transform=src.transform, dtype=rasterio.uint8) as dest_tiff:
            for i in range(temp.shape[2]):
                dest_tiff.write(temp[:, :, i], i + 1)
```

where `file` is my processed png file and has the same dimension as the `geo_file`.

In the remote machine, the geotiff is not saved with the georeferencing I had extracted out from `geo_file`. The bug is occuring in a remote VM but works perfectly fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had save the wrong file as tif. I was saving png as tif hence, the resultant tif image does not have any georeferencing. The above code works perfectly fine.